# VBA to create, rename and paste into a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA.

I'm looking to create some code that will filter a table on one sheet copy this then paste into a new sheet, whilst that new sheet has been renamed with today's date, then hiding the existing sheet again.  This is need weekly and possibly daily.

So far I have

```
Sub test2()
'
' test2 Macro
'    
'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Pipeline").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>"
    Range("Pipeline[[#Headers],[FC]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy


    Dim SheetName As String

    SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") 'Change the format as per your requirement
    Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
End Sub
```

This is filtering the range in the table and copying, and also creating the new worksheet.  But how do I then past into the new sheet then hide the sheet again.  Ideally I suppose the code needs to unhide the sheet to begin with.  The sheet name is `FC_Pipeline`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Ted

Answer (score 2):

This is to hide and create a new sheet with today's date

```
Sub Makro()
    Dim currentSheet As String
    currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName

    Sheets(currentSheet).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code would be like this

```
Sub test2()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet, newWs As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName As String

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Pipeline").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") 'Change the format as per your requirement

    Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    Set newWs = ActiveSheet
    Ws.Range("Pipeline[#All]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy newWs.Range("a1")
    Ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: I stepped through the code and it works up til this point `Ws.Range("Pipeline[#All]").Copy newWs.Range("a1")
    Ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden` It appears to be pasting the whole sheet and not the selected part as per this code `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Pipeline").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>"
    Range("Pipeline[[#Headers],[FC]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy`